# Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Tags: javascript, canvas, pdf.js

I have a button which on click executes this function.This code is to draw a line on canvas element on which PDF file gets rendered on a webpage by using PDF.JS.  But i get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null". What should i do.

```
function abc()
{
alert("msg");
var c=document.getElementById("canvas1");
alert(c);
var ctx= c.getContext('2d');
alert(ctx);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(300,150);
ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Do you have an element with the ID `canvas1`? The error strongly suggests you don't!

Comment: you also will have the same error if canvas1 is defined below the script tag that is using it

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you should check for null:

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas1");
if (c != null) {
  // proceed
} else {
  // a problem: what can you do about it?
}
```

Secondly, make sure you have an element `canvas1` - if it exists then `c` should not be `null`; if it doesn't exist then there's a discrepancy between the code and content, and you need to decide what should happen in circumstances when this occurs, if it should *never* occur then it's exceptional and maybe you want the error the be raised, or a message of your own specified, or something.

Comment: Im using pdf.js to render a pdf file on my website. I am not able to access the canvas on which the pdf file gets rendered on. this code is a part of the program. I have tried your solution and apparently 'c' is null. please help me if you know about pdf.js. Appreciate your help.

Comment: If `c` is `null` then you don't have a canvas with `id="canvas1"`. Change it to the ID of your canvas.

Answer (score 2):

I was using `var ctx= c.getContext('2D');` with the capital 'D' in 2D and that is not correct. It should be a lowercase 'd' in 2d. I realize this is a very simple error, but it brought me here. Hopefully I no one else starts to pull out hair on something so simple.

Comment: This answer has just saved my life. I was so confused, for such a simple error it is disappointing that there is no real way to detect it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the position of your script. I have included it in the `<head>` section so obviously, it tried to find `canvas` element even before letting it appended to the DOM. Thus giving `undefined` or `null` error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as far as I can tell (just added the following HTML):

```
<button onclick="abc()">button</button>
<canvas id="canvas1" height="300" width="300"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qBHRg/

Answer (score 0):

Touched up if it's stumbled upon recently.

```
// Canvas class to contain info about element and canvas
// and convenient API for drawing
var Canvas = function (id) {
    this.element = document.getElementById('my-canvas');

    // if canvas element doesn't exist...
    if (!this.element) {
        throw new Exception('Canvas $id not found.'.replace('$id', id));
    }

    // if the getContext method doesn't exist (old browser)
    if (!this.element.getContext) {
        throw new Exception('Canvas $id cannot load contexts.'.replace('$id', id));
    }

    this.context2d = this.element.getContext('2d');

    // if this particular context isn't supported
    if (!this.context2d) {
        throw new Exception('Canvas $id cannot load 2D context.'.replace('$id', id));
    }
};

// draw a line through each of the given points
Canvas.prototype.drawLine = function (points) {
    for (var i = 0, l = points.length; i < l; i++) {
        var point = points[i];

        // if it's the first point, start a path
        // otherwise, continue from the previous point
        if (i === 0) {
            this.context2d.beginPath();
            this.context2d.moveTo(point[0], point[1]);
        } else {
            this.context2d.lineTo(point[0], point[1]);
        }
    }
    this.context2d.stroke();
};

// create a reference point for our Canvas instance
var myCanvas;

// initialize our Canvas instance on page load
function initCanvas() {
    try {
        myCanvas = new Canvas('my-canvas');

        // draw a diagonal line from the top left to the bottom right
        // use actual width and height, not CSS properties,
        // unless you want blurred content
        myCanvas.drawLine([
            [0, 0],
            [myCanvas.element.width, myCanvas.element.height]
        ]);
    }
    catch(exc) {
        window.alert(exc);
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initCanvas, false);
```

Comment: Nothing wrong...I suspect OP has issue somewhere else in his code.   +1 to reverse someone else's minuses.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your alerts report that you have valid references to your canvas and context:

Alert#1:  `HTMLCanvasElement` and

Alert#2:  `CanvasRenderingContext2D` (or your browsers version of these)

Then the code you have presented will work in html5 canvas (no errors).

**Since you are working with pdf.js, your error might be in code you haven't shown us.**

Make sure you are feeding pdf.js a valid context

This alert should be `CanvasRenderingContext2D`

```
// test if the context you're feeding pdf.js is valid

alert(ctx);

// feed pdf.js the context

var myPDFContext = {
  canvasContext: ctx,
  viewport: viewport
};
page.render(myPDFContext);
```