# TypeScript: 'getContext' does not exist on type 'RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, canvas

I'm trying to useRef to get a refenrece to the canvas but typescript is complaining

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
const AddPhoto: React.FC = () => {
  const canvas = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = canvas.getContext('2d')!;
//                                                 ^ error
}
  return (
      <canvas
          ref={canvas}
          width={315}
          height={315}
     />
)
```

The error I get is

```
Property 'getContext' does not exist on type 'RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement>'.ts(2339)
```

if I change it to

```
    if (canvas && canvas.current) {
      const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = canvas.current.getContext('2d');
//           ^error

    }
```

the error is now

```
Type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D | null' is not assignable to type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'CanvasRenderingContext2D'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: try:
[he purpose of Typescript is to avoid wrong types. By default document.getElementById returns a HTMLElementtype which is a generic type. In order to make your app understand it is a canvas element you need to cast it using <CastedToType> syntax.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58218739/7943013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you use `useRef`, your value stores not just in `canvas` variable, but in `canvas.current`, so you should use `canvas.current.getContext('2d')`.

---

To fix type problem, use this instead of `if(...){...}`

```
const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D | null = canvas.current ? canvas.current.getContext('2d') : null;
```

Comment: Or use: `canvas.current?.getContext('2d')` so you can omit the ternary.

Comment: If acoiding the ternary, you would have to use ```const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D | null | undefined = canvas.current?.getContext("2d")```